# Cannot publish an RMarkdown HTML due to MASS package related problem

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, visualization

I generated an HTML file with RMarkdown. Then, I connected to Posit cloud. However, after clicking the button "Publish" and selecting the option of publishing the document on Posit Cloud, I get the following error:

> error=could not build image (image_id=: task image-build failed, task=, status=failed, error=error building image:
> Error fetching MASS (7.3-58.4) source.  unable to satisfy package: MASS (7.3-58.4)

Any ideas?

I tried commenting all the code related to tables and graphs to see if it has something to do with that (given that part of the error indicates incapacity to build an image) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error this morning, but I was trying to "publish" my shiny app that also contained R markdown documents.
I updated manually the MASS package and I solved the problem, despite being much slower than usual.

Comment: did you manually update on your local machine? Or on the server? I'm currently running into the same problem trying to publish an app to shinyapps.io, but I'm not sure how to force shinyapps to use a different version of MASS.

Comment: never had a problem on the server shinyapps.io, the shiny app was broken only on my local machine

Comment: @JakeThompson I was able to deal with this by installing the MASS package.